# xdebug never stops on single-line statements

Tags: php, intellij-idea, xdebug, phpstorm

Could you guys tell me why xdebug never stops on single-line statements ? I'm C++ guy so excuse me for lame question.

I'm using PhpStorm 5.0.2 as IDE. I tried it in Intellij IDEA Leda EAP as well.

Consider following php code

```
<?php
$d=date("D");
if ($d=="Fri")
{
    echo "Have a nice weekend!";
}
else
    echo "Have a nice day!";
?>
```

If I set break-point on second `echo` debugger will never stop there. But if I surround it with curly braces (like in case of first `echo`) it will.

It's quite unfortunate behavior which complicates debugging. Is it possible to change it somehow ? Maybe there is some secret xdebug setting ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug in PHPstorm. Does it stop if you set the breakpoint on the 'else'?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't stop on `else` either.

Comment: Bug then. Check on YouTrack to see if it's been added already and if not, file a new issue.

Comment: To ensure that it's PhpStorm bug and not xdebug issue first try to debug from some other IDE, like NetBeans.

Comment: @MattGibson But it not supposed to stop at `else` line -- there is nothing to execute. @ruslan Most likely it is xdebug issue, as PhpStorm only sends line numbers where to stop -- everything else (the decision to stop there) makes xdebug itself.

Comment: Sometimes it stops in odd places e.g. end of a multi line string, not the beginning. I agree with CrazyCoder: test in other IDE too.

Comment: Guys, it doesn't work in Notepad++ + DBGP Plugin v0.0.13.27 either. So it's xdebug bug :(

Comment: @MattGibson That's xdebug thing -- if you put breakpoint on multiline statement it will not hit it, but will work fine when it is on line line (where `;` is) -- for example: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in xdebug. I filed it ([0000895](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=895)) in their bug-tracking system. Please add your comments if you have any.

xdebug developer closed the bug with comment *"This is a duplicate of 0000842 - and sadly not something I can fix as it has to do with how the PHP interpreter assigns line numbers to generated execution units."*